# Метод девятичных дополнений/дополнение до девяти

Tags: математика

Всем привет. Начал читать книгу Андрея Столярова "Азы программирования" 1 том. В начале он рассказывает о Паскалине и о том как машина выполняет сложение и вычитание. Если сложение выполнялось просто, то для вычитания приходилось использовать метод девятичных дополнений.

Объяснение метода начинается с "Если у нас (для примера) всего пять разрядов, то перенос в шестой разряд, как и заём из него, благополучно теряется, что позволяет вместо вычитания числа выполнять прибавление некоторого другого числа."

Здесь мне не понятно каким образом, то что мы не можем занять из шестого разряда дает нам возможность выполнять сложение вместо вычитания. С переносом понятно, когда мы переносим в шестой разряд, значение теряется и остается ровно то, что нужно, а вот с заёмом не очень.

Может здесь есть те, кто разбирается в этой теме)

Как получить результат посредством дополнения до девяти мне понятно, но хотелось бы получше разобраться в этом методе.

Comment: Вместо того чтобы вычитать маленькое число, вы прибавляете большое. Происходит переполнение, шестой разряд теряется. Вы получаете нужный результат. Искусство состоит в построении "большого" числа по "маленькому".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @StanislavVolodarskiy. То что вы написали мне понятно, мне не понятно каким образом заём из шестого разряда дает нам возможность выполнять сложение вместо вычитания.

Comment: `то что мы не можем занять из шестого разряда`  - как раз-таки можем занять.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_calculator#Subtraction

Answer (score 1):

Я представляю это как механический счетчик, есть диск с цифрами 0-9.
Если в данный момент мы видим 0, и хотим увидеть 7,
можем повернуть на три позиции в одном напрвлении,
либо повернуть на 7 позиций в другом,
в обоих  случаях увидим 7.
Рассмотрим пример вычитания.

```
x-y 00555-00278
```

можно крутить в одну сторону, делая заемы в
разряде десятков и сотен, получается 00277.
Можно крутить в другую сторону,
представив
`100000 - 00278 = 99722`

`00555+99722=100277`, шестой разряд мы не видим.

```
x-y=x+(100000-y)-100000
```